# What is means of end:?

Tags: objective-c

At the end of a method, the following operations are defined:

```
end:
if (request.progress >= 1)
{
    request.decoderAttach   = nil;
}
[[LKImageMonitor instance] requestDidFinishDecode:request];
```

Does anyone know what is the end: means?
And,where does this end: come from?
Where can I find its definition?
Is there a similar definition in C++ or Objective-C?

Comment: `end:` looks like a `goto` label

Comment: And `goto` is C. Google "C goto".

Answer (score 0):

end: is the **goto** label it dosn't mean anything, it is use to go to the specific location in the program e.g.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter a number greater than 10: ";
    cin>>num;
    if(num < 10)
        goto end;
    cout<<"Number is greater than 10";
    end:
    return 0;
}
```